# Moving BIN files from C:\ drive - Hyper-v 2012

Tags: configuration, hyper-v

A lot of VMs have been created on a Server 2012 Hyper-V host and as a result the BIN files have started to encroach on the C:\ drive space.  I am guessing during their creation they have not looked to store the files elsewhere and as a result ProgramData is taking a huge chunk of space.

As a quick win I could change the option of the "Automatic Stop Action" from "Save" to "Shutdown the guest operating system" which would clear the space but I was hoping there was a way to move the files?  Everything I have read to date is all about changing the option to stop the Save State file being used but was hoping to keep that as an option...

Comment: The .bin and .vsv files are created in the same data root as the virtual machines, so your virtual machines are on the C: drive? Have you considered adding a new storage location for the virtual machines, such as another disk array?

Comment: indeed it looks like they have been created on the C:\.  there is a separate data drive that is there to host the VMs but it looks as if someone has been ignoring it.  The actual VHDs are on the Data drive though so they have done half measures it seems...

Comment: Right, in Hyper-V Settings there are two data locations: Virtual Machines and Virtual Hard Disks. It sounds like the Virtual Hard Disks location is set to the data drive and the Virtual Machines location is set to the C: drive. You can use the Move function to move the virtual machines to the data drive.

Answer (score 2):

In Hyper-V Settings there are two data locations: Virtual Machines and Virtual Hard Disks. The .bin and .vsv files are stored in the Virtual Machines location. It sounds like the Virtual Hard Disks location is set to the data drive and the Virtual Machines location is set to the C: drive. You can use the Move function to move the virtual machines to the data drive.